# Изменение значения переменной внутри MongoClient.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

У меня имеется ф-я collections, которая подключается к mongodb и подтягивает имена всех коллекций

```
  collections(){
let tempOptions = {
  reply_markup: {
    inline_keyboard: [[]],
    },
  };

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/",{useNewUrlParser:true},function(err,db){
    const _db = db.db('test');
    _db.listCollections().toArray(function(err,res){
    if (res)
      for (let i in res)
        tempOptions.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0].push([{text:res[i].name,callback_data:res[i].name}]);
  });
 });
 return tempOptions;
};
```

Однако tempOptions возвращается в исходном состоянии без изменений. Не могу понять почему, и как это исправить.

Comment: потому что функция отрабатывает быстрее, чем происходит подключение к БД

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом, но есть ощущение большущего костыля.

```
collections(){

    let tempOptions = {
      reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [[]],
        },
      };

    return MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/",{useNewUrlParser:true}).then(conn => {
        return conn.db("test").listCollections().toArray().then(res=>{
          for (let i in res)
           tempOptions.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0].push({text:res[i].toString(),callback_data:res[i].toString()});
          return tempOptions;
        });
      });
   };
```

Comment: Не знаю, какое у Вас приложение, но постоянно открывать соединение, наверное, не очень хорошая практика. Лучше было бы держать открытым соединение и постоянно через него обращаться к БД - тогда и проблем было бы меньше

Comment: Я согласен, чуть позже это поправлю